# Does Rails 4 have support for OR queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So in Rails 4 the long desired feature to use `not` queries has been added.

```
Article.where.not(title: 'Rails 3')
```

Has similar support been added for `or` queries, or are they planning to make it. I couldn't find anything by browsing through the release notes.

Obviously I tried

```
Article.where(title: 'Rails 3').or(title: 'Rails 4')
```

But that does not work.

Comment: if you like the syntax `Article.where(title: 'Rails 3').or(title: 'Rails 4')`, you could use [rails_or](https://github.com/khiav223577/rails_or).

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
Article.where(title: ['Rails 3', 'Rails 4'])
```

is how you'd do that in Active Record.

It's not possible to replicate any arbitrary SQL query using "Rails-y" syntax. But you can always just pass in literal sql.

So you could also do:

```
Article.where("articles.title = 'Rails 3' OR articles.title = 'Rails 4'")
```

Comment: True in this case. But this won't work for more complex conditions.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I know you can do it with arbitrary sql. But that is exactly what I was trying to avoid. I hoped, that since they added `not` queries, they would support `or` queries as well.

Comment: Obviously I can't speak to the future plans of the rails core team! You might try opening an issue on the github repo.

Comment: I might, or I will go ahead and try @PriteshJ's suggestion. That being said, your answer is correct and I will accept it now.

Comment: I guess the any_of gem is the only solution here?

Comment: In my case (rails 4.0.13), it dropped the records found from the first 'where' clause, and returned only those found in the 2nd clause.  Note I do have a 'join', and the clauses work fine separately.  Guess I have to write a class method to sum the IDs from each search, and then re-query with where(:id => id_set) - unless/until there is a way to sum AR sets.

Comment: You **really** should use `Article.where( "articles.title = ? OR articles.title = ?", "Rails 3", "Rails 4" )` to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: You aren't vulnerable to SQL injection if your query doesn't contain user input. `Article.where("articles.title = '#{some_var}'")` *might* be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, but `Article.where("articles.title = 'Rails 3' OR articles.title = 'Rails 4'")` is not.

Comment: Yes, but providing an example where they come from a user will make the answer better.

Answer (score 39):

This now works in Rails 5:

```
Article.where(title: 'Rails 3').or(Article.where(title: 'Rails 4'))
```

[Code example in Rails's source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/cases/relation/or_test.rb).

Comment: Even with this change in Rails 5, I would stick with @gregates answer and use this syntax `Article.where(title: ['Rails 3', 'Rails 4'])`. It's less verbose and matches the common usage of `Article.where(id: [1, 2, 3, 4])`

Comment: This solution has the advantage that you can use different columns in the two queries.

Comment: Another advantage is it works well with overriding methods that return queries `super.or(Article.where(title: 'Rails 4'))`

Answer (score 10):

The most common alternative is already answer by @gregates

Recently there has been pull request in rails source

[Add `#any_of` query method to active_record](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/10891)
Which adds or functionality to activerecord

the contributor has already created a gem incase its not accepted

its rails 3.2 and 4 compatible

https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of

I havent tried it yet but soon wish to use it looks good to me.

Answer (score 5):

I know that this is an old thread, but anyone else looking for a solution to this problem might find this code helpful:

```
Article.where(title: ["Rails 3", "Rails 4"])
```

Maybe that will help you get someone going in the right direction without having to risk sql injection.

Comment: What does this add to the (much older) accepted answer?

Comment: Compared to the accepted answer, I think this is cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: Of course, this only works if it's the same column. If it's different columns than you'll need to use the raw SQL for Rails 4.2 or less, and the new `.or` method for Rails 5+.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the rails master branch is now supporting OR queries. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052

I assume it will be in the framework with the next major release.

Comment: Yup, dhh said we'll have it in Rails 5: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052#issuecomment-72718557

Answer (score 2):

Rails 5 will support it but you can use this backport for Rails 4.2 : https://github.com/Eric-Guo/where-or