# How do I do a where OR on two columns in the same table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `membership` model, and I want to search `OR` on two columns....not sure how to do it.

I tried this:

```
u1.all_memberships.where(inviter: u2, invited: u2)
  Membership Load (6.8ms)  SELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships"  WHERE (memberships.user_id = 1 OR memberships.invited_id = 1) AND "memberships"."user_id" = 3 AND "memberships"."invited_id" = 3
=> []
```

But note the 2 `AND` on both queries, when ideally what I would like to do is literally just replace all the `AND`s with `OR`s.

So I would love if the query looked something like this:

```
Membership Load (6.8ms)  SELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships"  WHERE (memberships.user_id = 1 OR memberships.invited_id = 1) OR (memberships.user_id = 3 OR memberships.invited_id = 3)
```

Assuming that my modification is syntactically correct SQL ofcourse.

How do I do that with a `where` clause? Is that possible?

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192829/does-rails-4-have-support-for-or-queries there will be an `or` scope in rails5, until then, you can use `any_of` which is extracted to a gem.

Answer (score 2):

I expect It can help

```
where("inviter_id = ? OR invited_id = ? ", u2.id, u2.id)
```

DRYer solution

```
where("inviter_id = :uid OR invited_id = :uid ", uid: u2.id)
```

Comment: @marcamillion check out