# How to exclude a value from array with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a collection of posts from current_user and other 'followed' users displayed in a list. Posts can be marked anonymous on submit which hides the posters name (there is an 'anon column in the posts database that is either 1 or 0')

In my collection of posts, I want to show anonymous posts for the current_user, but exclude the anonymous posts from other users.

Here's what I have in my controller:

```
@feed = current_user.feed.where('anon != ?', '1')
```

The problem is it excludes all anonymous posts in my list.

Any ideas?

update:

Here is my feed method:

```
def feed
  following_other_ids = "SELECT followable_id FROM follows
                  WHERE followable_type = 'Other' AND follower_id = :user_id"
  following_user_ids = "SELECT followable_id FROM follows
                  WHERE followable_type = 'User' AND follower_id = :user_id"
  Post.where("other_id IN (#{following_other_ids})
                  OR user_id IN (#{following_user_ids})
                  OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
end
```

Comment: It sounds like you're going to need to use an OR to satisfy both conditions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192829/does-rails-4-have-support-for-or-queries

Comment: It worked! Thanks heaps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@feed = current_user.feed.where('anon != ? OR user_id = ?', '1', current_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
@feed = current_user.posts.where(anon: 0)
```

Comment: 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

Comment: it's View error, another line of code, not error from this line of code man

Comment: Sorry, I changed another bit of code while trying things and forgot to fix it before trying your solution. Your solution displays all 'anon' posts. But I want to display all posts except 'anon posts' from other users.

Comment: Edited. Just change it from 1 to 0