# How to use OR in ActiveRecord Rails 4.1.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm used scope  `where(address: [nil, ''], city: [nil, ''])` and I get request

```
WHERE ((`address`.`address` = '' OR `address`.`address` IS
NULL) AND (`address`.`city` = '' OR `address`.`city` IS
NULL))
```

I need replace `AND` to `OR`. How do I build a query using ActiveRecord?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192829/does-rails-4-have-support-for-or-queries

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
where("address.address in (?) or address.city in (?)", [nil, ''])
```

In application

```
scope :empty_address, -> { where("address.address in (?) or address.city in (?)", [nil, '']) }
Address.empty_address
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Arel gem](https://github.com/rails/arel) and form you query like:

ids = [nil,'']
`Address.where(Address.arel_table[:address].in(ids).or(Address.arel_table[:city].in(ids)))`

with [Arel-helpers](https://github.com/camertron/arel-helpers) you can make it even shorter:
`Address.where(Address[:address].in(ids).or(Address[:city].in(ids)))`